# Grep: Search for shorter file path, ignore longer file path

Tags: path, grep

I have an automation script that looks at `/etc/mtab`. In the example below, I want to use `grep` to find the string `nfs.example.org:/directory/subdirectory1` but ignore the string `nfs.example.org:/directory/subdirectory1/subdirectory2`:

```
nfs.example.org:/directory/subdirectory1
nfs.example.org:/directory/subdirectory1/subdirectory2
```

Unfortunately, `--word-regexp` doesn't work as I expected:

```
% grep --word-regexp /directory/subdirectory1 /etc/mtab
nfs.example.org:/directory/subdirectory1/subdirectory2 /directory/subdirectory1/subdirectory2 ...
nfs.example.org:/directory/subdirectory1 /directory/subdirectory1 ...
```

I thought `--word-regexp` would detect the first one but not the second one, since it should only match whole words:

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the
          line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or  followed  by  a  non-word  constituent
          character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

What else can I try to match the short path and not the long path?

Comment: `grep -Po 'nfs.example.org:/directory/subdirectory1(?=\s)' file`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Cyrus for pointing me in the correct direction. I had to use a series of quotations and whitespace to get a match. I'm actually calling this command in a for loop and via a parallel SSH script which means that whitespace & quotations are a little complicated.

The following worked for me:

```
for MNT in "/directory/subdirectory1 " /directory/subdirectory1/subdirectory2
do
    pssh hosta hostb hostc -c "grep -w '$MNT' /etc/mtab"
done
```